# How is Futures handled by threads

Tags: asynchronous, nonblocking, future, concurrent.futures

I often time hear the term asynchronous or non-blocking operations among the web domain. Usually they say that by encapsulating the time consuming operations as a Futures with the callbacks, threads does not block rather is notified when the callback returns.

How does this invoking a operation on the Future objects and being notified when the callback returns work under the hood with the web application context?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the language, framework and OS. I think this is too broad.

Comment: I want an example from any of them. I think the basic idea is similar among all.